# Creating a tuple using an associatedtype

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to alias a tuple type to use throughout my app. I do the initial aliasing like so:

```
associatedtype JSONReplacementValue = (key: String, value: AnyObject?)
```

Seems simple enough. When using this without an `associatedtype`, everything works fine. However, once I alias them, I get errors in the following two places:

```
var replacementValues: [JSONReplacementValue] = []
if let key = key {
    replacementValues.append((key: key, value: value))
}
```

This gives an error on the `.append` line, telling me `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(key: String, value: AnyObject?)`. I've tried replacing what I append to something like `JSONReplacementValue(key: key, value: value)` but that gives me an error `'Self.JSONReplacementValue' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

That's the first error I can't get around. The second happens in this code:

```
for replacementValue in values {
    json[replacementValue.key] = replacementValue.value
}
```

(values is an array of JSONReplacementValue, defined as a parameter like so `values: [JSONReplacementValue]`)

This gives me an error when I try to access `replacementValue.key`: `Value of type 'Self.JSONReplacementValue' has no member 'key'`. This one I have no idea how to solve it.

Is it possible to make a tuple an `associatedtype` at all? If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to create a typealias, you should try the `typealias` keyword. `associatedtype` works with protocols.

this code works fine with swift 2.2:

```
typealias JSONReplacementValue = (key: String, value: Any?)

var replacementValues: [JSONReplacementValue] = []
replacementValues.append((key: "one", value: "value"))
print(replacementValues) // prints: [("one", Optional(value))]
```

Also bear in mind that `AnyObject` is for class types while `Any` for all types.

Another thing is you'd be better off with a Struct instead of a Tuple.

From Apple Docs:

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple. For more information, see Classes and Structures.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for any looking in the future. I had this declared in a protocol definition. The methods were all in the protocol extension. By changing it a `typealias` and moving it into the extension, everything worked as expected.